# Qt creator not seeing Mac Frameworks

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, opencl

I am using Qt 5.6 with Qt Creator 4.3 on macOS Sierra 10.12.

I am building a Qt based application that uses OpenGL and OpenCL.

Software or system updates somewhere appear to have broken Qt Creators' ability to find the headers for OpenGL and OpenCL headers.

I have tried reinstalling Qt, Reinstalling Xcode and the Mac SDK and none of these options make it work.

The weird thing is my app compiles. QtCreator just cannot find the headers itself - this makes code navigation somewhat more complex.

So lets take OpenCL. I include it like this:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#endif
```

My app.pro file for qmake has the following inside it:

```
macx:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -framework OpenCL
```

And with this it seems to compile. However the two OpenCL #include above in QtCreator are yellow underlined with a tooltip saying "OpenCL/cl.h: No such file or directory".

Now I can see that it compiles successfully as qmake is working out where the frameworks are and appending the paths successfully:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/Users/me/Projects/app -I. -I/Users/me/Qt5.6.2/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/me/Qt5.6.2/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/me/Qt5.6.2/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I/Users/me/Qt5.6.2/5.6/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/me/Qt5.6.2/5.6/clang_64/lib -o main.o /Users/me/Projects/app/main.cpp
```

Now if I navigate to the following directory the headers are there and present:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A`

So I cannot see what is missing.

I have tried to "teach" Qt Creator about this framework directory with combinations of the following, but I havent found something that will work:

```
macx:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -framework OpenCL
macx:INCLUDEPATH += /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Headers
macx:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
macx:LIBS += -framework OpenCL
```

I'm struggling to find information about how QtCreator find the system frameworks on a mac and how i get it to start finding them again. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody that has the same problem the answer was actually rather simple in the end.

When you setup the kit in Qt creator (which tells it what compiler and debugger to use amongst other things) you need to be careful with the compiler used. I had two copies of clang on my machine, one was installed in /usr/bin (the system one) and the other was installed inside the XCode app bundle. My kit was using the Xcode installed one as thats where the libraries live. While this compiled just fine, Qt creator for some reason does not hook up the paths to libraries properly. Simply switching this over to using the one in /usr/bin solved it.

Note that i did not explicitly ask it to use the one in the Xcode app bundle, thats just the one that was automatically selected when the project was first opened in Qt creator. So you might have to adjust its default behaviour in order to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late to help OP, but for anyone else with this problem, you can force Qt Creator to recognize the latest Xcode by going to the Build directory and doing:

```
    rm -rf .qmake.stash
    rm -rf .qmake.cache
```

This can happen when upgrading Xcode, for example.

You can confirm what's going on by showing includes in your .PRO file:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -showIncludes # Windows
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -H. # Mac
```

Look for "-isysroot" in Compile Output. Or open `.qmake.stash` with a text editor.